# Replacing a pattern to the end of a file with sed

Tags: linux, unix, sed

Using sed, if there is a space character on a line in a file, I need to print the output with the space character and anything after it removed. Code example:

```
sed "s/"something here I think"//g' file
```

So, let's say a file says this on a line:

```
 Chuck Norris is the man
```

I just need it to print:

```
 Chuck
```

Multiple lines applicable too:

```
Chuck Norris is the man
So is Arnold
```

Replaced:

```
Chuck
So
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
sed 's/ .*//g'  file
```

To remove from the beginning of the line to the first space, use this:

```
sed 's/^[^ ]* //g'
```

Comment: But what if I need to remove the first space and anything before it? I did sed 's/.* //' file and that did not work appropriately.